# 80-net-setup-link no longer functions when I downgraded systemd

Tags: arch-linux, udev, systemd

I've downgraded systemd to version 208. Although I still have `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` on my disk, but the names of network interfaces were not named correctly:

e.g `wlp3s0` is not renamed to `wlan0`, and so is `enp0s25` to `eth0`

Any ideas? I want the names back to wlan0 and eth0

P.S I'm running Arch Linux, I marked `systemd` and a few other package for upgrade

```
warning: systemd: ignoring package upgrade (208-11 => 210-2)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the names back to wlan0 and eth0? Those are being phased out.

Comment: @slm Yes I'm trying to get the names back

Comment: Are you just doing this temporarily or are you planning on doing this going forward?

Comment: @slm I want this persistent. Or are you talking about the downgrade of systemd?

Comment: Sorry, are you planning on manually maintaining wlan0, eth0 going forward w/ every update?

Comment: @slm Yes. It just suddenly stopped working, I'm not sure why

Comment: OK, interesting, I have 204 (Fedora 19) and it uses the wlp3s0, so your issue isn't that systemd was using wlan0 and switched, you were overriding this already, and it just stopped working on you now.

Answer (score 2):

You use a `udev` rule to enable the device names that you want: see [the Arch wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Device_names).

Essentially, create a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network-name.rules` like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="5aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", NAME="ether"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="gg:hh:ii:jj:kk", NAME="wifi"
```

Note the warning about *not* using `ethx` or `wlanx` as names to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `80-net-name-slot.rules` instead of `80-net-setup-link.rules` for the filename in release v197 through v208. This is documented [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).